# How to use float16 neon intrinsics on Android?

Tags: android, c++, arm, neon, half-precision-float

How do I use arm float16 intrinsics on Android?

Consider the following program:

```cpp
#include <arm_neon.h>

int main(int, char** argv) {
    const float16x8_t a = vdupq_n_f16(1.0F);
    const float16x8_t b = vdupq_n_f16(- 1.0F);
    const float16x8_t c = vaddq_f16(a, b);
}
```

and the following cmake file:

```bash
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(test CXX)
add_executable(test main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g -march=${MARCH}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -march=${MARCH}")
target_compile_options(test PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -g)
target_compile_features(test PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

instantiated with the following command:

```bash
cmake -DCMAKE_ANDROID_API=26 -DANDROID_PLATTFORM="26"\                             
              -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a \
              -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/tmp/android-ndk-r25c  \
              -DCMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE=c++_static -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a\
              -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DMARCH=armv8.2-a -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -S . -B build_android
```

When compiling the program, I get the following error:

```bash
/tmp/float16/main.cpp:6:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'vaddq_f16'
    const float16x8_t c = vaddq_f16(a, b);
                          ^
```

I understand, that float16 is available with [Arm-v8.2](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101028/0012/13--Advanced-SIMD--Neon--intrinsics). Furthermore, the function `vaddq_f161` is guarded by the ifdef `#if defined(__ARM_FEATURE_FP16_VECTOR_ARITHMETIC)` in `arm_neon.h` . Under which condition is this flag set to true when compiling a program for Android? The Android [ABI notes](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis) say that
arm64-v8a refers to Arm-v8.0 only. Is there a way to use float16 intrinsics on Android?

Comment: Update the cmake command line to `-DMARCH=armv8.2-a+fp16` or other appropriate values (such as `+bf16` superset) as described in [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could verify this. Do you want to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: You can self answer and upvote the people who wrote the gcc documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question (and referring to the comments of the question above):

float16 intrinsics can be used with the option `-DMARCH=armv8.2-a+fp16` . See the [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html), listing the architecture options.